# WP_Query custom post type by multiple custom fields

Tags: php, custom-post-type, custom-fields, wordpress

Alright guys, I'm in way over my head.

I'm trying to build a filter for a custom post type, 'Villas'. These villas have multiple custom fields, these custom fields exist in a group named 'features'.

I've build a search / filter form that POST's the data, which I'm then able to capture using a $_GET request.

The data I'm sending includes: 
- **Region, type, style** select fields; 
- **Sea view, Sea access, Swimming pool, Reform project** checkboxes; 
- **Price** input field

What I'm trying to accomplish is get a query going that filters all 'Villas' using the form values. After extensive googling I found it is possible to loop through custom post_type's with custom fields by using meta_key's. Basicly what I'm trying to do is:

```
    $propertyPrice      = $_GET['price'];
    $propertyRegion     = $_GET['region'];
    $propertyType       = $_GET['type'];
    $propertyStyle      = $_GET['style'];
    $hasSeaview         = $_GET['seaview'];
    $hasSeaAccess       = $_GET['sea-access'];
    $hasSwimmingPool    = $_GET['swimming-pool'];
    $hasReformProject   = $_GET['reform-project'];

    if( isset($propertyPrice) || isset($propertyRegion || isset($propertyType)) || isset($propertyStyle) || isset($hasSeaview) || isset($hasSeaAccess) || isset($hasSwimmingPool) || isset($hasReformProject)) {
        $args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR'
                array(
                    'key'   => 'property-price', 
                    'value' => $propertyPrice,
                ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'property-region', 
                    'value' => $propertyRegion,
                ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'property-type', 
                    'value' => $propertyType,
                ),
                etc......
            )
        );
    }
```

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to filter through the posts with variable meta values, send from the form.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be extremely appreciated.

---

To give you an idea, this is what the filter looks like:

[Custom post type filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg9Ew.png)

---

**EDIT** 
After xphan's suggestion I edited my code like so, however the var_dump returns nothing even though the _GET's are filled correctly.

```
<?php
    $propertyPrice      = $_GET['price'];   
    $propertyRegion     = $_GET['region'];
    if($propertyRegion === 'all') { $propertyRegion = array('ibiza-city', 'southwest', 'north', 'east', 'center'); }
    $propertyType       = $_GET['type'];
    if($propertyType === 'all') { $propertyType = array('villa', 'apartment', 'plot'); }
    $propertyStyle      = $_GET['style'];
    if($propertyStyle === 'all') { $propertyStyle = array('rustic', 'modern'); }
    $hasSeaview         = $_GET['seaview'];
    if( isset($hasSeaview) ) { $hasSeaview = 1; }
    $hasSeaAccess       = $_GET['sea-access'];
    if( isset($hasSeaAccess) ) { $hasSeaAccess = 1; }
    $hasSwimmingPool    = $_GET['swimming-pool'];
    if( isset($hasSwimmingPool) ) { $hasSwimmingPool = 1; }
    $hasReformProject   = $_GET['reform-project'];
    if( isset($hasReformProject) ) { $hasReformProject = 1; }
?>

<?php

echo $propertyRegion .'<br>';
echo $propertyType .'<br>';
echo $propertyStyle .'<br>';
echo $propertyPrice .'<br>';
?>
<?php  if( isset($propertyPrice) || isset($propertyRegion) || isset($propertyType) || isset($propertyStyle) || isset($hasSeaview) || isset($hasSeaAccess) || isset($hasSwimmingPool) || isset($hasReformProject)) { 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'villas',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'property-price', 
                'value' => $propertyPrice
            ),
            array(
                'key'   => 'property-region', 
                'value' => $propertyRegion,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'   => 'property-type', 
                'value' => $propertyType,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'   => 'property-style', 
                'value' => $propertyStyle,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'   => 'sea-view', 
                'value' => $hasSeaview
            )
        ) 
    ); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php var_dump($the_query->the_post()); ?>

<?php
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass **an array of values** to the `value` attribute of your `meta_query`. Further you can specify the relation the target meta values must have with your provided values.

Here is an example where you search for a post that has (besides the matching `propert-price` meta value) either `value1` or `value2` saved in the meta field `property-region`

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR'
        array(
            'key'   => 'property-price', 
            'value' => $propertyPrice,
        ),
       array(
            'key' => 'property-region',
            'value' => array('value1', 'value2'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Typo. Below the `relation => OR`, the array needs a comma before it.